# FFMPEG remove codec x264 to final films

Tags: ffmpeg

I am processing my movie in ffmpeg (file merging, stabilization). The resulting metadata file gets an x264 codec. What prevents it from being reprocessed?

I decided to remove the codec using the Internet.
script:

```
    ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c copy -map 0 -metadata creation_time="2017-09-18 13:30:04" output.mp4
ffmpeg -i output.mp4 -vcodec copy -acodec copy -vbsf h264_changesps=removesei -map_metadata -1 out.mp4
pause
```

Unfortunately it does not work:

> Unknown bitstream filter h264_changesps

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Only questions about programmatic use of the FFmpeg libraries, API, or tools are on topic here. Please ask your question at [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/)

Comment: If you do not know the answer then why are you giving the dung? and you're still asking me questions !!!

Comment: You need a custom version of ffmpeg. See https://video.stackexchange.com/q/18227/1871

Comment: @Mulvya, thanks :) work